# Connecting to Pgpool

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Apologies for the long post but i'm stumped on getting Pgpool to work for me.

Running Centos7 i have two instances of Postgres running on different ports in master replication mode.

I have successfully installed pgpool-II.

Starting pgpool i get the output :

```
[root@PLHSISRV035 pgpool-II-96]# pgpool -n
2018-02-07 16:21:54: pid 118373: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:9999
2018-02-07 16:21:54: pid 118373: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::9999
2018-02-07 16:21:54: pid 118373: LOG:  find_primary_node_repeatedly: waiting     for finding a primary node
2018-02-07 16:21:54: pid 118373: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0
2018-02-07 16:21:54: pid 118373: LOG:  find_primary_node: primary node id is 0
2018-02-07 16:21:54: pid 118373: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version     3.7.1 (amefuriboshi)
```

So from here i should be able to connect using :

```
psql -l -p 9999 (default settings)
```

Instead i get the standard not running Postgres error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.9999"?
```

Can anyone help. ?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix, was to include the database and user flags while connecting.